# Adding line number and file name to 3 column files using awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a couple of data sets containg x, y, z coordinates in plain text format (no column headers, whitespace delimited, crlf line breaks). Data looks like this:

```
10168522 21059480 -86
10169988 21058886 -86
10171457 21058291 -86
10172926 21057706 -86
10174428 21057114 -85
10175927 21056531 -85
10177434 21055952 -85
10178966 21055370 -84
10180473 21054773 -85
10181992 21054164 -85
10183517 21053557 -85
```

In this example, the filename is "fileA.xyz". I'd like to add the line number and the filename to the file and print it out using awk (actually gawk 4.0.2 with no option of upgrading / installing additional tools).
I have come up with the following

`awk -F ' ' -v OFS=' ' -v ORS=' ' '{$1; $2; $3; $(NF+1)=++i FS "fileA.xyz"}1' better_fileA.xyz`

which kind of works, but leaves the first line untouched:

```
10168522 21059480 -86
 1 fileA.xyz 10169988 21058886 -86
 2 fileA.xyz 10171457 21058291 -86
 3 fileA.xyz 10172926 21057706 -86
 4 fileA.xyz 10174428 21057114 -85
 5 fileA.xyz 10175927 21056531 -85
 6 fileA.xyz 10177434 21055952 -85
 7 fileA.xyz 10178966 21055370 -84
 8 fileA.xyz 10180473 21054773 -85
 9 fileA.xyz 10181992 21054164 -85
 10 fileA.xyz 10183517 21053557 -85
```

I've also noticed an extra white space in front of the line number (first column). I do understand awk is very complex, but I am a bit lost amidst the syntax options. For starters, I'm wondering why the order of columns I provided is apparently not passed on to the output?

Since all files are very large (couple of gigs), I'd like to use awk / sed. Also note that files need to be consistent, hence solutions involving `cat -n` are not really an option (due to the padding of line numbers in the file, which is not reasonable in this scenario where the range of line numbers is not known a priori and also because this would not take care of the filename).

Any suggestions or pointers towards a solution would be very welcome!

Comment: Try `awk '{print NR, "fileA.xyz", $0}' better_fileA.xyz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the filename is hard-coded, this short one-liner should help:

```
$ awk '$0=NR FS "fileA.xyz" FS $0' YourFile
```

Basically, it prepends the stuff (lineNo# and the filename) to each record, and prints to stdOut.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot. It is quite easy to get drawn into the rabbit hole. Haven't found a solution this concise anywhere on the web. 
I'd still like to understand why the first line was skipped in my original post?

Comment: Can also use the `FILENAME` built-in variable rather than the `"fileA.xyz"` hard-coded string literal. `awk '$0=NR FS FILENAME FS $0' YourFile`. And if you want to get the line number of the file processed and process multiple files at once: `awk '$0=FNR FS FILENAME FS $0' file1 file2 file3 ...`

Comment: While this will produce the expected output in this case, to avoid surprises in general don't use the result of an action as a condition unless you have a specific need to do so. We frequently see people doing this and then be surprised when some lines don't get output. Always do `awk '{action}1'` instead of `awk 'action-as-condition'` unless you **need** the latter.

Comment: Great suggestion about the use of variabes instead of hard coding the filename. To be honest, this is used within an f string in python, so it's a very abstracted example.

Comment: I don't know what "an f string in python" is but calling awk from python instead of doing whatever you want directly in python can't be the right approach.

Comment: @LéaGris No, using the built-in `FILENAME` is not the right case for OP's problem. He is NOT expecting to insert the input file's name into the content.

Comment: @EdMorton You are absolutely right, Sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{printf "%3d %s %s\n", NR, "fileA.xyz", $0}' better_fileA.xyz 
  1 fileA.xyz 10168522 21059480 -86
  2 fileA.xyz 10169988 21058886 -86
  3 fileA.xyz 10171457 21058291 -86
  4 fileA.xyz 10172926 21057706 -86
  5 fileA.xyz 10174428 21057114 -85
  6 fileA.xyz 10175927 21056531 -85
  7 fileA.xyz 10177434 21055952 -85
  8 fileA.xyz 10178966 21055370 -84
  9 fileA.xyz 10180473 21054773 -85
 10 fileA.xyz 10181992 21054164 -85
 11 fileA.xyz 10183517 21053557 -85
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your input **appears** to be getting skipped (but isn't really) because your input file has DOS line endings (`<CR><LF>`) so those `CRs` are causing the text you add to 1 line to appear at the start of the next line instead of at the end of the current line. See [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Regarding your script:

1. `-F ' ' -v OFS=' '` doesn't make sense as you're setting those to the default values they already have.
2. `-v ORS=' '` doesn't make sense as you don't want your output crammed all onto 1 line.
3. `$1; $2; $3;` doesn't make sense as it doesn't do anything except reference the field for no reason.
4. `$(NF+1)=++i` doesn't make sense as `i` will then always have the value of `NR`.
5. Populating/modifying a field (e.g. `$(NF+1)`) or `$0` unnecessarily is inefficient since it then causes awk to re-construct and/or re-split `$0`.

It's also not clear from your code (which is trying to append fields) and your current output (which shows prepended fields that you seem happy with), what you really are trying to do - append or prepend fields. Also clarify if `"fileA.xyz"` you're adding to the output can be derived from the input file name `better_fileA.xyz`

One guess at what you might want is:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} {print $0, NR, "fileA.xyz"}' better_fileA.xyz
10168522 21059480 -86 1 fileA.xyz
10169988 21058886 -86 2 fileA.xyz
10171457 21058291 -86 3 fileA.xyz
10172926 21057706 -86 4 fileA.xyz
10174428 21057114 -85 5 fileA.xyz
10175927 21056531 -85 6 fileA.xyz
10177434 21055952 -85 7 fileA.xyz
10178966 21055370 -84 8 fileA.xyz
10180473 21054773 -85 9 fileA.xyz
10181992 21054164 -85 10 fileA.xyz
10183517 21053557 -85 11 fileA.xyz
```

or maybe:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} NR==1{fname=FILENAME; sub(/[^_]*_/,"",fname)} {print $0, NR, fname}' better_fileA.xyz
10168522 21059480 -86 1 fileA.xyz
10169988 21058886 -86 2 fileA.xyz
10171457 21058291 -86 3 fileA.xyz
10172926 21057706 -86 4 fileA.xyz
10174428 21057114 -85 5 fileA.xyz
10175927 21056531 -85 6 fileA.xyz
10177434 21055952 -85 7 fileA.xyz
10178966 21055370 -84 8 fileA.xyz
10180473 21054773 -85 9 fileA.xyz
10181992 21054164 -85 10 fileA.xyz
10183517 21053557 -85 11 fileA.xyz
```

or maybe:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} NR==1{fname=FILENAME; sub(/[^_]*_/,"",fname)} {print NR, fname, $0}' better_fileA.xyz
1 fileA.xyz 10168522 21059480 -86
2 fileA.xyz 10169988 21058886 -86
3 fileA.xyz 10171457 21058291 -86
4 fileA.xyz 10172926 21057706 -86
5 fileA.xyz 10174428 21057114 -85
6 fileA.xyz 10175927 21056531 -85
7 fileA.xyz 10177434 21055952 -85
8 fileA.xyz 10178966 21055370 -84
9 fileA.xyz 10180473 21054773 -85
10 fileA.xyz 10181992 21054164 -85
11 fileA.xyz 10183517 21053557 -85
```

Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need the line numbers to be in a perfectly lined-up column :

```
mawk 'NF~FNR{__=_ FILENAME _} $!NF=NR __$_' RS='\r?\n' FS='^$' \_=' ' better_fileA.xyz
```